# Extract part of string(/soup element) within a list of lists

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having some issues with scraping fish images off a website.

```
species_with_foto = ['/fangster/aborre-perca-fluviatilis/1',
 '/fangster/almindelig-tangnaal-syngnathus-typhle/155',
 '/fangster/ansjos-engraulis-encrasicholus/66',
 '/fangster/atlantisk-tun-blaafinnet-tun-thunnus-thynnus-/137']

titles = []
species = []
for x in species_with_foto:
    specie_page = 'https://www.fiskefoto.dk'+x
    driver.get(specie_page)
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    brutto = soup.find_all('img', attrs={'class':'rapportBillede'})
    species.append(brutto)
    #print(brutto)
    titles.append(x)
    try:
        driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[13]/div[2]/div/div').click()
        print('CLicked next', x)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Succesfully finished - :', x)
    time.sleep(2)
```

This returns a list of lists with the sublist looking like this:

```
[<img alt="Aborre (Perca fluviatilis) aborrefiskeri, striber, rygfinne, regnorm, majs, spinner, " class="rapportBillede" src="/images/400/aborre-perca-fluviatilis-medefiskeri-bundrig-0,220kg-24cm-striber-rygfinne-regnorm-majs-spinner-358-22-29-14-740-2013-21-4.jpg" style="width:50%;"/>,
  <img alt="Aborre (Perca fluviatilis) aborrefiskeri, striber, rygfinne, regnorm, majs, spinner, " class="rapportBillede" src="/images/400/aborre-perca-fluviatilis-medefiskeri-prop-flaad-med-levende-skalle-paa-enkeltkrog-1.6kg-46cm-6604-1724617.jpg" style="width:calc(50% - 6px);margin-bottom:7px;"/>]
```

How can i clean up the list and only keep the `src="/images/400/aborre-perca-fluviatilis-medefiskeri-prop-flaad-med-levende-skalle-paa-enkeltkrog-1.6kg-46cm-6604-1724617.jpg"` - part? I have tried with other variables in the soup.find_all but can't get it to work.

(The selenium part is also not functioning properly, but I'll get to that after......)

EDIT:

This is my code now, I'm really getting close :) One issue is that now my photos are not saved in a list of lists but just a list - I for the love of god don't understand why this happens?

Help to fix and understand would be greatly appreciated!

```
titles = []
fish_photos = []

for x in species_with_foto_mini:
    site = "https://www.fiskefoto.dk/"+x
    html = urlopen(site)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    titles.append(x)
    
    try: 
        images = bs.find_all('img', attrs={'class':'rapportBillede'})
        for img in images:
            if img.has_attr('src'):
                #print(img['src'])
                a = (img['src'])                     
                fish_photos.append(a)
    except KeyError:
        print('No src')
        
    #navigate pages
    try:
        driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/form/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[13]/div[2]/div/div').click()
        print('CLicked next', x)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Succesfully finished -', x)
    time.sleep(2)
```

EDIT:

I need the end result to be a list of lists looking something like this:

fish_photos =

```
[['/images/400/aborre-perca-fluviatilis-medefiskeri-bundrig-0,220kg-24cm-striber-rygfinne-regnorm-majs-spinner-358-22-29-14-740-2013-21-4.jpg',
 '/images/400/aborre-perca-fluviatilis-medefiskeri-prop-flaad-med-levende-skalle-paa-enkeltkrog-1.6kg-46cm-6604-1724617.jpg',['/images/400/tungehvarre-arnoglossus-laterna-medefiskeri-6650-2523403.jpg', '/images/400/ulk-myoxocephalus-scorpius-medefiskeri-bundrig-koebenhavner-koebenhavner-torsk-mole-sild-boersteorm-pigge-351-18-48-9-680-2013-6-4.jpg'],[ '/images/400/graeskarpe-ctenopharyngodon-idella-medefiskeri-bobleflaad-med-toastbroed-paa-enkeltkrog-5.02kg-77cm-6436-7486.jpg','/images/400/graeskarpe-ctenopharyngodon-idella-medefiskeri-bobleflaad-med-toastbroed-paa-enkeltkrog-10.38kg-96cm-6337-4823146.jpg']
```

EDIT:
My output now is a list with identical lists. I need it to put every specie in its own list, like this: fish_photo_list = [[trout1, trout2, trout3], [other fish1, other fish 2, other], [salmon1, salmon2]]

My initial code this, but not now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, you can change:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "[insert name of the site]"
html = urlopen(site)
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

try: 
   images = bs.find_all('img')
   for img in images:
       if img.has_attr('src'):
          print(img['src'])
except KeyError:
    print('No src')
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another issue with the lists after implementing this change, would appreciate your help :)

Comment: Please rate(score) me....     Send me a problem.

Comment: add:  a = img['src']    and change:   fish_photos.append(a).  try and contact me

Comment: If i do that within the "try: " the end result is still a list with all images and not a list of lists

Comment: Dont know how to contact you

Comment: which list do you want? please show example picture.

Comment: fish_photos = []   and add new list and set fish_photos,   list_fish_photos = []   
list_fish_photos .append(fish_photos )

Comment: I think you want this?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a list in a list.

Comment: My output now is a list with identical lists. I need it to put every specie in its own list, like this: fish_photo_list = [[trout1, trout2, trout3], [other fish1, other fish 2, other], [salmon1, salmon2]]

Comment: If you want to do it, you need to know in advance which fish the link belongs to. can you do that? also you can create free list(trout,salmon1...)  and last merge all list.

Comment: if links contains fish names, you can also split full list by text.

Comment: Yes i know which fish it is by going through this loop: for x in species_with_foto:
    site = "https://www.fiskefoto.dk/"+x

Comment: species_with_foto = ['/fangster/aborre-perca-fluviatilis/1',
 '/fangster/almindelig-tangnaal-syngnathus-typhle/155',
 '/fangster/ansjos-engraulis-encrasicholus/66',
 '/fangster/atlantisk-tun-blaafinnet-tun-thunnus-thynnus-/137']

Comment: list_all = ['fish_trout',   'fish_trout1',   'fish_trout3',   'salmon1',   'salmon2']

Comment: trout = [s for s in list_C if "trout" in s]
       salmon = [s for s in list_C if "salmon" in s]

Comment: want_list = [trout, salmon]

Comment: Combine the above three comments. Searches for fish by text and links automatically  ;)

Comment: Tell me which site you scrape and I will help you as soon as I get the information.

Comment: I'm scraping this page first https://www.fiskefoto.dk/alle-danske-fiskearter to get a list like this: [https://www.fiskefoto.dk/fangster/aborre-perca-fluviatilis/1, https://www.fiskefoto.dk/fangster/atlantisk-tun-blaafinnet-tun-thunnus-thynnus-/137, https://www.fiskefoto.dk/fangster/ansjos-engraulis-encrasicholus/66]

Comment: I then go through that list and wants to save all 'src' values in separate lists so i can later download all images

Comment: you can one list(all src), second split more list by text(then is above my code). and the end create last list and append lists.

Comment: Thaks I'll try!

Comment: Yeees - got it!

Comment: okay, very good